# missing expression in Select SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL and sub queries, When I run the sub query by itself I get the correct data output. But when I run the full query I get the error message

> SELECT   * Error at line 3: ORA-00936: missing expression

Here's my code:

```
SELECT 
MAX(
    SELECT 
    SUM(
        ALLOCATION.HourlyRate 
        * 
        ACTION.HrsWorked
        ) 
    FROM ALLOCATION 
    INNER JOIN ACTION 
    ON ((ACTION.ActId  = ALLOCATION.ActId) AND (ACTION.EmpId  = ALLOCATION.EmpId)) 
    GROUP BY (ALLOCATION.ActId)
)
FROM ALLOCATION
GROUP BY (ALLOCATION.ActId)
```

SOLUTION:

```
   SELECT MAX(sum_total_pay)
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(ALLOCATION.HourlyRate *  ACTION.HrsWorked) AS sum_total_pay
    FROM ALLOCATION 
    INNER JOIN ACTION 
    ON ((ACTION.ActId  = ALLOCATION.ActId) AND (ACTION.EmpId  = ALLOCATION.EmpId))
    GROUP BY (ALLOCATION.ActId)
);
```

Comment: try removing all those useless parentheses - especially those around the columns in the `group by` clause. But the scalar sub-query in the `select` list doesn't really make sense. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'd do a derived table based query instead. You can't do a SELECT in the SUM().

Comment: I'm trying to find the maximum 'total pay' which is the sum of all the products of an hourlyRate column and an hrsWorked column for a given activity Id. i.e. activity 1 'python coding' may have a total pay of (3*4 +5*10.5 + 12*16) while activity 2 'testin' may have a total pay of (4*10 + 5*8) and I need to find the maximum total pay of these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needs two parentheses more :)

```
  SELECT MAX ( (  SELECT SUM (ALLOCATION.HourlyRate * ACTION.HrsWorked)
                    FROM ALLOCATION INNER JOIN ACTION ON (ACTION.ActId = ALLOCATION.ActId) AND (ACTION.EmpId = ALLOCATION.EmpId)
                GROUP BY (ALLOCATION.ActId)))
    FROM ALLOCATION
GROUP BY ALLOCATION.ActId
```

The Select into MAX have to be in paranthesis.

The logic is not clear. This give you the total pay per activity:

```
  SELECT ALLOCATION.ActId, SUM (ALLOCATION.HourlyRate * ACTION.HrsWorked) total_pay
    FROM ALLOCATION b INNER JOIN ACTION ON ACTION.ActId = ALLOCATION.ActId AND ACTION.EmpId = ALLOCATION.EmpId
GROUP BY ALLOCATION.ActId
```

If you want to see, which activity has the biggest payment, then order by desc :

```
  SELECT *
    FROM (  SELECT ALLOCATION.ActId, SUM (ALLOCATION.HourlyRate * ACTION.HrsWorked) total_pay
              FROM ALLOCATION b INNER JOIN ACTION ON ACTION.ActId = ALLOCATION.ActId AND ACTION.EmpId = ALLOCATION.EmpId
          GROUP BY ALLOCATION.ActId)
ORDER BY total_pay DESC
```